# sql queries to show the most popular record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have four tables

1. **Car** (`car_ registration_no, class, type_code`)
2. **Rental_history** (`rent_date, car_registration_no, rent_location_code, return_location_code`)
3. **Type** (`type_code, make, model`)
4. **Location** (`location_code, branch_name`)

I need a query to show the most popular car rented by location.
I need a query to show the total rentals at each location for the previous month?

My code so far is as follows, but I couldn't complete it:

```
SELECT car.class, car.type_code , type.make, type.model 
  FROM car , type, rental_history 
 where rental_history.car_registration_no = car.car_registration_no 
   and car.type_code = type.type_code
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Both these types of queries would be covered by a basic Sql tutorial. Count Sum, group by and join.

Comment: i have tried these till now and i couldn't complete it 

SELECT car.class, car.type_code , type.make, type.model
FROM  car , type, rental_history 
where rental_history.car_registration_no = car.car_registration_no
and car.type_code = type.type_code

Comment: looks like *four* tables to me

Comment: It would really helpful if you could provide some sample data and expected results, as “most popular car” can be either a specific car (by `car_registration_no`) or a car of a specific class (by `class`), or even something else…

Comment: it should appear for example if customers rented corolla 2 times and Lexus 4 times in London Branch. so the reslut would be (London    Lexus)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 4):

You will need to join the tables and calculate the numbers. Let's start off with an easier query to point you in the right direction.

This will show you how many times a "type_code" car has been rented per location (untested, may contain errors)

```
SELECT
    count(car.car_registration_no) as rental_num,
    car.type_code,
    rental_history.rent_location_code
FROM car
LEFT JOIN rental_history ON (rental_history.car_registration_no = car.car_registration_no)
GROUP BY car.type_code, rental_history.rent_location_code;
```

I'm using a left join here because there may be cars that have not been rented and won't have any history. Instead of not showing up, you will have a "0" for number of rentals.

**Edit:**

For the second query it's actually very straightforward. You need to group by location, filter on date and use COUNT (again, untested):

```
SELECT
    count(rental_history.car_registration_no) as rental_num,
    rental_history.rent_location_code
FROM rental_history
WHERE rent_date >= '2012-03-01' AND rent_date < '2012-04-01'
GROUP BY rental_history.rent_location_code;
```

Comment: what about the second query? do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @user1348163 please mark as solved if my answer answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Join All the table and use count..!

Comment: i am new on this man. i dont know how to join them and do that. can you help some more

Comment: i tried these. and couldn't complete it 

SELECT car.class, car.type_code , type.make, type.model
FROM  car , type, rental_history 
where rental_history.car_registration_no = car.car_registration_no
and car.type_code = type.type_code